# POST method not supported using Laravel 6 and ReactJS?

Tags: reactjs, laravel

I am trying to add some data to my MySQL database using Laravel 6 and ReactJS.

I am getting this error:

```
Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\MethodNotAllowedHttpException
The POST method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: GET, HEAD.
```

I am not sure where is the problem, since I have the POST method in the Routes.

And here are my files:

**Routes: web.php**

```
Route::get('/{any?}', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});

Route::post('/addproduct', 'StoreProductsController@store');
```

**Model: Products.php**

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Products extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = ['name', 'stock', 'broken'];
}
```

**Controller: StoreProductsController.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Products;

class StoreProductsController extends Controller



{
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $products = new Products();

        $products->name = request('name');
        $products->stock = request('stock');
        $products->broken = request('broken');
        $products->save();

        return redirect('/storage');
    }
}
```

**ReactJS Component: Storage.js**

```
<form method="post" action="/addproducts">

    <div class="form-row">
         <div class="form-group col-sm-12 col-md-6">
              <label for="inputNombreProductos">Producto</label>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputNombreProductos" placeholder="Nombre del producto..." name="name"></input>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group col-sm-12 col-md-3">
               <label for="inputCantidadProductos">Cantidad</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputCantidadProductos" placeholder="Cantidad de productos..." name="stock"></input>
           </div>

            <div class="form-group col-sm-12 col-md-3">
                  <label for="inputNombreProductos">Dañados</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputNombreProductos" placeholder="Nombre del producto..." name="broken"></input>
            </div>
     </div>
     <button type="submit" className="btn btn-primary">Agregar</button>
```

If anyone know how to solve this problem I would really appreciate it. Thanks in advance.

When I run the command ***php artisan route:list*** this is what I get:

```
| Domain | Method   | URI        | Name | Action                                             | Middleware   |
+--------+----------+------------+------+----------------------------------------------------+--------------+
|        | POST     | addproduct |      | App\Http\Controllers\StoreProductsController@store | web          |
|        | GET|HEAD | api/user   |      | Closure                                            | api,auth:api |
|        | GET|HEAD | {any?}     |      | Closure                                            | web          |
```

Comment: What is the out put of `php artisan route:list`

Comment: Added to the main post.

Comment: It's a typo: `/addproducts` vs `/addproduct`. Will remove my answer

Comment: there you have it.

Comment: Already corrected the typpo, and now I am getting 419
Page Expired

Comment: Do you send the csrf token with your form somewhere?

Comment: I am not sure how to send it using the form in a React component, any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You should never create wild-card routes like this

```
Route::get('/{any?}', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});
```

because all of your invalid routes will get mapped to this one. But in case for some reason you need to have this try moving it to the end of your route file.

Comment: I am using that wild-card route because I am using React Router to make a SPA.

Comment: Just noticed there is a type in your component form action

Answer (score 0):

can you use annotations in your controller to add POST methods ? 
In symfony i did that :

```
/**
     * @Route("/add_notification/{email}", name="add_notification", methods={"POST"})
     * @param Request $request
     * @param SerializerInterface $serializer
     * @return Response
     * @throws Exception
     */
```

I don't know if Laravel support that or not